# Anyone have any experiences with SuperMicro Layer 3 Switches (SSE-G48-TG4 in particular)

Tags: switch, supermicro

We use a lot of SuperMicro gear, and we just noticed that SuperMicro now has a Layer 3 managed switch.  I am interested in using it in a top of the rack application.

As with most of SuperMicro stuff, the price is right.

I can't seem to find anyone online who has tested/reviewed/used on of these switches.  Before plunking down the money, I wanted to find a review or hear someone's good experiences with this gear.

Anyone used a SuperMicro layer 3 switch (particularly SSE-G48-TG4) and have anything good or bad to say about them?

Comment: Well, did you buy the switch? I`m looking forward to buy the very same switch - i wonder how it has been working for you (if you use it).

Comment: We purchased the switch -- it works, but because of the software/config differences from the hp/cisco gear we are used to, we paid a major penalty.  Basically, we got it working in the end but it was like performing brain surgery on oneself.

Comment: At our company, it's a good competitor to be our first managed switch. Pity no reviews cannot be found on that switch. (About performance, reliability etc). This page comes almost on top :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning! this is a content free answer...

This looks like a [broadcom reference design](http://www.broadcom.com/products/Switching/Enterprise/BCM56514) based switch.  I'm pretty sure that either all the major network gear makers or everyone but cisco use these as the basis for their product.  It actually looks like a newer generation than is in use in most other current switches (the give-away is the 4 10g uplink ports on a 48 port gig switch).

The glossies for this switch really hit all the right bullet points (ospf/bgp/ssh management/vrrp/spanning tree).  The list price is a little lower than what we typically get for more "name brand" switches, which is impressive.

I've always had good experiences with supermicro as well but I'd want to get a demo before pulling the trigger on this sort of thing.  They're new enough in that market that they'd probably be willing to ship you one as a demo.

You're comfortable with not having a "channel partner" to "help" you, right?

Comment: I'll just add that I've used several different vendors' "broadcom reference switch" switches and despite the fact that they're all basically the same, they're totally different.  What they *do* is the same but the user-interface and the quality of the boxes make a *huge* difference.  One vendor has a box that has a nice UI but the fans fail and the switches overheat; others make boxes that are kludgy to use but that have amazing features and that simply *never* fail.  All I'm really saying is that you really need to put your hands on one and make sure you can live with it before you buy it.